# Error on Clicking Categories in Admin

Tags: magento-2.1, category, error

[image]

[image]

The log in the report is this.

> a:4:{i:0;s:97:"The requested component ("settings") is not found.
> Before using, you must add the implementation.";i:1;s:9651:"#0
> /home/u783663984/domains/ukmadesweets.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(207):
> Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\Provider\Component\Definition->getComponentData('settings')

Does anyone know the fix for this. I am a beginner so would appreciate some instructions as I cant access my Categories in the Admin pannel at the moment.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using a new module (not compatible with <= 2.2 Magento version) with the old Magento. Since 2.2 the `<settings>` added to the definition list of ui components, but in the old version you had to use `argument/data/config`. Try to find this module in the project using search (by string `<settings>`) and disable it. After that - clear the cache and try to open the categories menu, it should work.

The better solution would be to update your Magento to the latest version 2.4.4, but this can be very difficult (from 2.1.x to 2.4.x).

Old definition without `<settings>`: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition.xml

New one (part) with the `<settings>` definition for elements: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/ui_settings.xsd